How to allow java.util.Date as a Hibernate type in version 6 using reverse engineering (hbm2java)
I am upgrading Hibernate from 5 to 6 and having issues with the reverse engineering. I want all entities to continue using java.util.Date for now, but seems the mapping is now java.sql.Timestamp. I am running it through the maven-antrun-plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution> <!--mvn antrun:run@hbm2java -->
            <id>hbm2java</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" />
                    <hibernatetool destdir="${reveng.destdir}">
                        <classpath>
                            <path location="${basedir}/target/classes" />
                        </classpath>
                        <jdbcconfiguration propertyfile="path/to/hibernate.properties" revengfile="path/to/hibernate.reveng.xml" packagename="${reveng.packagename}" detectmanytomany="true" />
                        <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
                    </hibernatetool>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-ant</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

I am planning on migrating java.util.Date to java.time, however that is a much larger project and not in scope for this upgrade.
I am looking to have the entities continue to show dates like:
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="created")
private Date created;

However it is generating as:
@Column(name="created")
private Timestamp created;

Setting the type mapping to java.util.Date ends up setting java.sql.Timestamp:
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="DATE" hibernate-type="java.util.Date"/>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="TIMESTAMP" hibernate-type="java.util.Date"/>
    </type-mapping>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>

Not setting JDBC DATE to java.util.Date defaults to java.sql.Date, so I know the mappings is doing something, just not sure how it is overriding and how to prevent that.
I tried setting the type on the column as well, which does the same thing.
Any help on how to make the generation to use java.util.Date would be appreciated.

I ended up overriding this through templates. You set the templatepath attribute in the plugin and write a template files. The specific part that does this for me is:
<#foreach property in pojo.getAllPropertiesIterator()>
    <#if pojo.getMetaAttribAsBool(property, "gen-property", true)>
        <#assign javaType = pojo.getJavaTypeName(property, jdk5)>
        <#if javaType == "java.sql.Date" || javaType == "Timestamp">
            <#assign javaType = '${pojo.importType("java.util.Date")}'>
        </#if>
        ${pojo.getFieldModifiers(property)} ${javaType} ${c2j.keyWordCheck(property.name)}<#if pojo.hasFieldInitializor(property, jdk5) && !(c2h.isManyToOne(property) && property.getValue()?exists)> = ${pojo.getFieldInitialization(property, jdk5)}</#if>;
    </#if>
</#foreach>

